White powder on Dracaena

Please help me to understand what this is and how to eradicate this.

This is a bad case of mealy bug which is tricky to control.
This answer should assist you
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/52501/499

If you see a white powdery substance on your Dracaena plant, it could mean a few different things:
Powdery mildew: This is a common fungal disease that affects many plants, including Dracaena. Apparently white powdery substance on the leaves.
To treat, you can try removing affected leaves, improving air circulation around the plants and applying fungicidal sprays specifically formulated to combat powdery mildew.
Mealybugs: These are small, soft-bodied insects often found as white, cotton-colored clusters on the leaves and stems of plants. A white powdery residue can be left behind, which is actually a waxy discharge.
To get rid of mealybugs, you can wash the affected areas with water and dish soap, or apply insecticidal soap or neem oil.
Mineral deposits: Residual white powder can sometimes be minerals left by hard water or coal. This causes less damage to the plant compared to fungi, diseases or insects.
You can wipe the leaves with a damp cloth to remove these deposits.

Please don’t throw out wild guesses. For a gardener, the difference between mealy bugs, powdery mildew and mineral deposits is so significant, that I see no reason to mention all of them here.
